# How to handle (with LVM or DM (device mapper)) when a drive has gone away and come back as a new block device

Tags: linux, lvm, device-mapper, virtio

(This correct answer is to one that bears little surface resemblance to this one. Asking the question and answering it myself with reference to that one.)

Consider a virtual host environment in which a VM has been assigned 3 separate `virtio` drives, appearing as 3 separate block devices, and assigned to 3 separate VGs (volume groups).

- os - `/dev/vda` - vgroot
- db - `/dev/vdb` - vgdata
- var - `/dev/vdc` - vgvar

While the VM is online, `/dev/vdb` goes away. This could be due to the VM being moved to a new hypervisor but that particular volume got stuck, or perhaps the insane system administrator removed the volume and put it on another host temporarily. In my case, I was feeling lucky.

When the volume comes back, the Linux Kernel (not all, actually; but at least since RHEL6) assigns it not to its original drive letter, because that disk is technically seen as 'open', but to a new block device: `/dev/vdd`.

Afterwards, all the LVM commands, such as `vgs`, report :

```
/dev/data/db: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 10733158400: Input/output error
/dev/data/db: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 10733215744: Input/output error
/dev/data/db: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
/dev/data/db: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
```

However, `pvscan` and `vgscan` detect the original volumes, but they're still trying to read the old block device. Re-mounting doesn't work. And for the sake of argument, rebooting is unacceptable. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered in a related discussion on `iscsi` disks [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59566/105631). Since i'm not working with scsi at all, but rather `virtio`, Google searches weren't helping find my answer. If you're coming across this answer, make sure to upvote Guiseppe's answer. In short, it's:

```
vgscan ; vgchange <vgname> --refresh
```